# Using SQL Server stored procedure to match column name to variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

UPDATED.

I made modifications to the Store Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Labor_Rates_By_CompanyID]
--Get_Labor_Rates_By_CompanyID '5116' ,'FOREMAN-REGULAR TIME (8hr Day Monday-Friday)* (HR)'

@CompanyID bigint,
@Labor_Type nvarchar(200)

AS
BEGIN

Select COLUMN_NAME from 
[Emerald_Data].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where TABLE_NAME= N'tbl_Client_List_Pricing' and 
COLUMN_NAME=@Labor_Type

Select * from tbl_Client_List_Pricing
where [CompanyNum]= @CompanyID

END
```

After Running I have the following two tables from the select statements:
[image]

I need to combine the two statements so the top COLUMN_NAME result filters the second Select to only show that Column and it's data for the Client Alston Construction. The Top COLUMN_NAME also exists in the bottom select as a COLUMN_NAME

The End Result Should look like:

```
Client                |   FOREMAN-REGULAR TIME(8hr Day Monday-Friday)* (HR)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alston Construction   |   45
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Given code does not have invalid syntax. It is supposed to be somewhere near dynamic sql.

Comment: Something mysterious is going on here. Are you asking about magic formulas that are supposed to perform computations based on "column name"? Where would you take that column from if `select *` does not return it? And where did `invalid syntax` exception go?

Comment: By editing the content of your question, you've now made my answer look completely irrelevant. It's better just to ask a new question if you have a **new** question. I have updated my entire Answer now to match the usage of your new parameter names so that it's not confusing to whoever visits this page in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to the current version of your question (Please do not update it again):**

You don't need to `SELECT` the column name from the table by itself first and then try to join it to the query you want. Your `SELECT * FROM tbl_Client_List_Pricing` already contains the column `'FOREMAN-REGULAR TIME (8hr Day Monday-Friday)* (HR)'`, so you can use dynamic sql to do this:

For example:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = N'SELECT [Client], [' + @Labor_Type + ']' + '
FROM tbl_Client_List_Pricing
WHERE [CompanyNum] = @CompanyID'

--PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```

To provide you with the results:

```
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|       Client        | FOREMAN-REGULAR TIME(8hr Day Monday-Friday)* (HR) |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| Alston Construction |                      45                           |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

---

**Your original question:**

You asked why you were getting the following error, when trying to execute a stored procedure like this:

```
sp_Get_Labor_Rates_By_CompanyID '5204' 'STRAW WATTLE > 10000 LF-INSTALLED-Photo (LF)'
```

> Incorrect syntax near 'STRAW WATTLE > 10000 LF-INSTALLED-Photo (LF)'

---

**My Answer:**

When you execute a stored procedure with more than one parameter, use a comma between your parameters.

---

Check out [Execute a stored procedure or function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql)

As you'll see there, you could either supply the parameter names:

```
[ [ @parameter = ] { value   
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ]   
                           | [ DEFAULT ]   
                           }  
        ]
```

Execution:

```
sp_Get_Labor_Rates_By_CompanyID @CompanyID = '5204', @Material_Type = 'STRAW WATTLE > 10000 LF-INSTALLED-Photo (LF)'`
```

OR

Supply them in the order given in the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement (at the time of execution):

```
[ ,...n ] 

sp_Get_Labor_Rates_By_CompanyID '5204', 'STRAW WATTLE > 10000 LF-INSTALLED-Photo (LF)'
```

> If you supply parameters in the form @parameter = value, you can supply them in any order. You can also omit parameters for which defaults have been supplied. If you supply one parameter in the form @parameter = value, you **must** supply all subsequent parameters this way. If you do not supply parameters in the form @parameter = value, you must supply them in the order given in the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

Comment: I made modifications to the Post.  Please take a look again.  Thank you!

Comment: That will not work as FOREMAN-REGULAR... is a variable based on the COLUMN_NAME returned.  It's not the only COLUMN that can be returned from `@Labor_Type`

`Select Client, @Labor_Type from tbl_Client_List_Pricing
where [CompanyNum]= @CompanyID`

Returns:

Client                                   |       (No column name)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alston Construction         |   FOREMAN-REGULAR TIME...

`@LaborType` needs to be used to get the correct COLUMN_NAME and return it's Value based on the `@CompanyID`

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are asking now. I have updated my answer. You want to use `['+@Labor_Type+']`

Comment: Invalid column name for that value.  I am using MSSQL.  I'm not sure if that might be for MySQL or not.  

`

Comment: Ok Thanks.  I can't even Alter the SP because it's showing red as an invalid column name: `Select Client, ['+@Labor_Type+'] from tbl_Client_List_Pricing
where [CompanyNum]= @CompanyID`             `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Get_Labor_Rates_By_CompanyID, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 18]
Invalid column name ''+@Labor_Type+''.`

Comment: Thanks to Brien, I would have not have found this otherwise. I was able to get it working by using dynamic sql. I read the risks but since I am trying to use a variable as a column name many posts show no other way of accomplishing this without dynamic sql.

`declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = 'select [' + replace(@Labor_Type, '''', '''''') + '] from 
tbl_Client_List_Pricing where [CompanyNum]=' + replace(@CompanyID, '''', 
'''''')

exec sp_executesql @sql`

Comment: updated to use dynamic sql example, and yes there are risks with sql injection. You can help with this by using a `CASE` statement to ensure the parameter contains what you want it to contain. If this question is complete, please mark an answer accepted.